# Drupal 7 - Add Items to multiple places in a menu

Tags: 7, routes

I'am trying to set up a menu layout which has two links to /our-public-awareness-campaign; one under "Voter", and one under "News centre". The problem I'am running into is that although I can have two links in different parts of the menu, when looking at the page it will always try to open the menu to only one of them. This means that if you are looking under "Voter", and you go to "Our public awareness campaign", suddenly you're in a different location of the site. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks, Ruslan

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a feature not available in Drupal core. The issue is being worked on, but does not currently have a solution: http://drupal.org/node/609542

In the meantime, one potential solution is to use path aliases to the same node. Thus you might have /voter/our-public-awareness-campaign and /news/our-public-awareness-campaign which both point at a particular node. Drupal should treat the two menu entries as unique/separate then, and thus only the one you want to show as the menu should be activated.

Comment: If the feature isn't available in Drupal core, is it available in a module somewhere?

Comment: There are two options which may help you:
Special menu items module - http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items
Menu position module - http://drupal.org/project/menu_position
But it depends on your needs. With the release of 7.9 a module could be built using the new set_active_trail functions to help fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[NodeSymlinks](https://drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks)

> NodeSymlinks allows you to display the same content to users at multiple locations in the Drupal menu system with unique URL path, unique navigation breadcrumb and without the SEO penalty that usually occurs with multiple copies of the same content.
>
> This is useful when you want to have the same page reachable though multiple menu items, each with its own URL, menu trail and breadcrumb path.

Answer (score 0):

For one off thing like this, I tend to just use jQuery to change the active trail.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that NodeSymlinks does the job perfectly. We had the problem that we have a submenu in the sidebar. If you put the node into the menu twice, only in one location the Submenu opens correctly. In the other location the same submenu is shown as in the first one.

When you install Menu Symlinks, you have to manage the alternate menu entries through the node form. This had me baffled for a while. It is neither on the Node Symlinks Admin page, nor in the Menu Admin Section.

This is the settings form inside the Node Menu settings:

[image]